# Obtaining a Mac's System Profiler data from shell

Tags: macos, system-profiler

How can I retrieve the information shown in the Mac's System Profiler app programatically? I'm actually interested in the USB section if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [system_profiler(8)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) command.

Answer (score 3):

The OSX command line tool "ioreg" might give you want you want.

> man ioreg 
>   ioreg displays the I/O Kit registry.  It shows the heirarchical registry as an inverted tree.

Also if you can/want to use Cocoa look at [IOKit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html).  IOKit is the OSX framework that talks to USB hardware.

Comment: I think this is almost what I'm looking for. Two things though, I don't see the Volume information associated with the USB disk, for example the mount point. Second, is there a way to filter the output to get USB devices only?

Comment: An easy way to see OS X volume information from the command line is either using df (I usually use "df -h" for human readable format) or using  diskutil (command line tool is basically Disk Utility.app).  If you run "diskutil list" that will show you volume information.