# Obtain available/free RAM of computer in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, ram

I'm looking to get the value of available/free computer RAM in Swift 2.2. I've read [this answer by Viktor Latypov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10830858/4353019) which suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583736/determine-physical-mem-size-programmatically-on-osx). Unfortunately, the question asked about "physical memory size" (total memory i.e. 16 GB), but I am looking for "available/free memory".

I've also read about the `NSProcessInfo` class, but the `physicalMemory()` function is not what I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a trivial thing to do. For a working example, you can examine this  source code: https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit

Comment: If you don't mind going down to the command line, `vm_stat` may deliver what you are looking for. Check its `man` page for details

Comment: @Code Different I am familiar with `vm_stat`. I was rather looking for a native method of obtaining free RAM information through Swift, though `vm_stat` might be a last-resort if there is no other native method.

Comment: I think you have to dive pretty deep into the Mach kernel for that. Check out [host_statistics](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/host_statistics.html)

Answer (score 3):

After spending too much on this, I couldn't go any further, so I'm putting what I have so far up here in the hope that someone can help improve it.

You can get results similar to `vm_stat` on the command line with `host_statistics`:

```
func vw_page_size() -> (kern_return_t, vm_size_t) {
    var pageSize: vm_size_t = 0
    let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&pageSize) { (size) -> kern_return_t in
        host_page_size(mach_host_self(), size)
    }

    return (result, pageSize)
}

func vm_stat() -> (kern_return_t, vm_statistics) {
    var vmstat = vm_statistics()
    var count = UInt32(sizeof(vm_statistics) / sizeof(integer_t))
    let result = withUnsafeMutablePointers(&vmstat, &count) { (stat, count) -> kern_return_t in
        host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_VM_INFO, host_info_t(stat), count)
    }

    return (result, vmstat)
}


let (result1, pageSize) = vw_page_size()
let (result2, vmstat) = vm_stat()

guard result1 == KERN_SUCCESS else {
    fatalError("Cannot get VM page size")
}
guard result2 == KERN_SUCCESS else {
    fatalError("Cannot get VM stats")
}

let total = (UInt(vmstat.free_count + vmstat.active_count + vmstat.inactive_count + vmstat.speculative_count + vmstat.wire_count) * pageSize) >> 30
let free = (UInt(vmstat.free_count) * pageSize) >> 20

print("total: \(total)GB")
print("free : \(free)MB")
```

The total memory tallied to less than what `NSProcessInfo` returns. On my Mac with 16GB of memory, the total returned was about 15.6GB.

Calculating free memory is more problematic: there are lots of inactive and purgeable pages, but Mac OS X doesn't like to purge them until there's no more free page. So while it appears that I have only 450MB available, there are a lot more that I can use if an app needs it. And don't forget about memory compression, available since Mavericks (10.9)!